# Java for loop with equality operator in the second condition

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print an array in reverse order.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String []argh) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();

        }

        for (int j = n-1 ; j == 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

In this code nothing happened, but when I changed the second condition in the 2nd for loop from `j == 0`  to `j >=0` it worked. I don't understand why . In `j==0`, isn't that supposed to decrement `j` until it becomes equal to `0`?

Comment: In your first loop, do you expect it to increment `i` until `i` becomes less than `n`, or until it *stops* being less than `n`? Apply the same logic to your second loop.

Answer (score 6):

`for (int j = n-1 ; j == 0; j--)` means that the loop will execute as long as `j` is equal to `0`. Since `j` is initialized to `n-1`, the loop is never executed (assuming n != 1).

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to a `for` loop is the loop condition: it specifies the condition under which the loop body will execute.  The body will execute *while* the condition is true, **not** *until* it is true.

Note how your first `for` loop works: `i` starts at `0`, and it loops *while* `i < n`.  It's the same principle in your second loop, only your loop variable moves in the opposite direction: `j` starts at `n - 1`, and should loop *while* `j >= 0`.

All conditional loops in Java (`while`, `for`, and `do-while`) work in this way: they loop only as long as the condition holds, then they terminate, and execution picks up after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `j==0` the condition will be false, because j is given a value which is equal to n-1, `j=n-1`.
Suppose the value of n is 3, so j will be equal to 2 then it'll come to condition checking part in for loop, in that part you've written like this `j==0`, since j isn't equal to 2 so the condition will be false and it'll come out of the for loop.